# link back to previous page using $_SERVER HTTP REFER?

Tags: php, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do a “back” link on PHP pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851714/how-can-i-do-a-back-link-on-php-pages)

Can someone please show me where i am going wrong. I have a link accessible from various pages that goes to another page, once the user is done on that page they can click a link 'back' which should take them to the previous page they was on.

I am trying to use the following code but it won't respond, won't link to anywhere and just stays on the current page.

If anyone can offer a way of doing what i am trying to achieve that be great thanks.

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>"><< Back</a>
```

Comment: Also note that this input header isn't always defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `echo` the result.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>"><< Back</a>
```

Otherwise, PHP will not print anything.